# Book immortals go through a gate to get to the immortal source

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years ago (it’s 2018 now) I was reading a lot of Poe literature and I think that this story may be written by Poe but I am not completely sure.

Universe: Past or present, not future

The world is split in to two groups: 
 1. Immortal slaves
 2. Mortal masters with some supernatural powers. With these powers they can manipulate slaves.

Story:
A group of mortal masters with a few immortal slaves are on a journey to find some source of immortality. I think it was some gate or something.  The story is about their journey to this source.

In the end they found the immortality source and they had to do something naked (not what you think, more like drink something or go through the gate).
But the plot is that they become immortal but they lost their abilities, so they become immortal slaves.

There were previous slaves waiting for the mortals to go through the gate. When they did, those slaves just steal the mortals’ clothes and run away. So the new immortal slaves come out of the gate and have to wait for new clothes from a new group of mortal masters.

Comment: What do you mean by Poe literature?  As far as I remember Edgar Allan Poe didn't write any stories that seem similar.  Or do you mean something else with "Poe Literature"?